# How to avoid the validation of X-Forwarded-Proto in jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using jetty with forcedHost and SSL configuration. Be default jetty is validating input X-Forwarded-Proto header to be present. How to avoid this?

Trying to avoid the validation of X-Forwarded-Proto.

Without this header getting below error.

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Access Denied"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is not doing that validation.

The optional `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` which exists to parse forwarding headers and populate the `HttpServletRequest` does not validate the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in the way you are experiencing (the Jetty code only makes sure that there is a value, any value on that header before using it, ignores the header if the value is not present), nor does `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` produce that style of error response.

Something else in your webapp is doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are using jetty for mutual auth. Is there any relation between this header and client subject DN?